# Taking a Value from a Database and storing it in Another database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, logic

I have event names that are stored into my user database. How would I go about taking that event name from the user and storing it into the UserEvent's name column in the UserEvent database. For example, the user created an event called NewEvent, how would I set NewEvent as the name of a UserEvent in that UserEvent database?

Comment: Why would you store the same thing on two different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't store the same thing in two different places, and if it's the requirement of your database, you can `delegate` this thing as follows:

```
class UserEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :name, to: :new_event
end
```

I strongly hope that a `UserEvent` somehow has a relation to an event.

If you really like to store the same thing in two different places, I would suggest using a call back like `after_create` or `after_save`, so each a `NewEvent` object is created, or modified, take its name, and store in another model.

Comment: So the User that created the event, that event would be stored in the UserEvent model's database with the delegate command correct?

Comment: No, delegate doesn't work like this. Delegate means if you try to call `name` on `UserEvent` model, it will fetch the name from associated `NewEvent` model.